# Prove that $COV(h(x),g(x)) \leq 0$ means the different direction for $h,g$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

(Covariance Inequality)

Prove that if $g$ is nondecreasing and $h$ nonincreasing, then $$ E(g(X)h(X)) \leq E(g(X)) E(h(X)) $$

---

I know that it is equivallent to prove $COV(g(X),h(X)) \leq 0$ if $h$ nondecreasing and $g$ nonincreasing. I don't know how to even approach to the problem because there are no conditions such as the continuity of $g,h$.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked and answered before on the site, so I shall be brief. Consider $Y$ an independent copy of $X$ and integrate the almost sure inequality
$$
(g(X)-g(Y))\cdot(h(X)-h(Y))\leqslant0.
$$